# Docker Stack Deploy not updating environment settings

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-stack

Given the following compose file:

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world
    environment:
     - test:test
```

If I deploy it using `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test`, then modify the compose file as follows:

```
services:
  hello-world:
    image: hello-world
    environment:
     - test:test
     - test2:test2
```

Now if I run `docker service inspect test_hello-world` I see the following in the task template:

```
"Env": [
    "test:test"
],
```

Is there a command I can use to get the second environmental variable (test2) added from the compose file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, please run after updating docker-compose to update service: `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test`

**Explanation**:

Please, run `docker ps -a` after running `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test`. You can see that the status of the container is `Exited (0)`. It means that your container is not running at that time.

After docker-compose.yml update with `test2:test2` and running `docker service inspect test_hello-world`, you **are not updating** your service **automatically**.

You should run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test` again after `docker-compose.yml` changes with `test2:test2` to update. Then you can see that it was updated. I tested it to be sure that it works like that.

Output:

```
 "Env": [
      "test2:test2",
      "test:test"
  ],
```

You can also test with `nginx` instead of `hello-world`.Because it always runs (up). After updating docker-compose, pls run `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml test` to update.

Terminal:

```
Updating service test_hello-world (id: m8le589r3cqap8yg3acega0te)
```

At that time, the previous version was terminated, and a new version was created. `docker ps -a` shows it.

Terminal (docker ps -a):

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
10a90caaa627   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 seconds ago        Created                       test_hello-world.1.rcrbfttxqw0j22mkw0l149etp
130db6b1d3da   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp    test_hello-world.1.hdbj9bjt72sw45obx7h6nga77

docker service inspect test_hello-world
...
"Env": [
   "test2:test2",
   "test:test"
 ],
```

Comment: You are correct. I was looking under prespec... and the update wasn't working in the system I had, but the error was masked. Thank you.